# mysql query not fetching data from where condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a MySQL query ?I want to fetch data `t.taskid = b.id OR t.taskid = '0' AND t.subtaskid = j.id  OR t.subtaskid = '0'` from this but where condition is not working for this

```
SELECT t.id as id
     , t.taskid
     , t.subtaskid
     , p.PNAME AS projectname
     , t.date AS DATE
     , b.Summary AS tasks
     , j.SUMMARY AS subtasks
     , t.mon AS time1
     , t.tue AS time2
     , t.wed AS time3
     , t.thu AS time4
     , t.fri AS time5
     , t.sat AS time6
     , t.sun AS time7  
  FROM bt_createissue b
     , bt_createissue j
     , timesheet t 
  LEFT
  JOIN bt_project p 
    ON t.projectid = p.pkey  
 WHERE t.taskid = b.id 
    OR t.taskid = 0 
   AND t.subtaskid = j.id  
    OR t.subtaskid = 0 
   AND t.date >= '2015-03-09' 
   AND t.date <= '2015-03-30' 
   AND t.username = '$username'
```

Comment: Give us some sample data, the result you expect, and what you get when you run your query.

Comment: I think you need some parenthesis in your conditions like `(t.subtaskid = j.id  OR t.subtaskid = '0' )`. And also for the `(t.subtaskid = j.id  OR t.subtaskid = '0' )`. Otherwise, you will need add the datasets so that everyone can look into the root of the problem.

Comment: Some tips: Don't use comma style joins AND definitely don't use comma style joins in conjunction with OUTER JOINs. Use parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

If `t.taskid = b.id
t.subtaskid = j.id` are to be joins then check whether you can modify

`WHERE t.taskid = b.id OR t.taskid = '0' 
AND t.subtaskid = j.id  OR t.subtaskid = '0'`

the above lines with proper joins.
Because using join conditions in where clause can create cross join instead of intended one.

If it do not work

Try with using `having clause` instead of `where clause` and don't forget to use `group by`